# Need to find the IP Address of a HomeKit device

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

I am wondering if anyone knows of a good way to find the ip of a HomeKit device whether through the accessory or it's services. I've scoured the HMAccessory's and HMService's properties to no avail, but maybe I'm missing something.

I though about possibly using bonjour, but I haven't been able to find much documentation (or examples) on using it to find HomeKit devices, so hopefully there's a better way.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: I doubt this is possible with HomeKit, but I do know that depending on the device you plan on using, you can extract the IP address using the devices' IOS SDK libraries if they have one. For example, with philips devices I'm pretty sure you can do this, with TI devices, and I mean low low level chip boards, I know for a fact that you can do this.

Comment: Thanks Larcerax, in your opinion would it worth embedding the devices ip address in a characteristic on the devices side?

Comment: I wouldn't do that only because IP addresses can change, FROM  MY EXPERIENCE, with services like Comcast or other internet providers. I've noticed that they usually don't employ static IP addresses for locations and I wouldn't count on this. If the user makes any crappy changes to their Wifi/router/internet service, then you may have issues. I would try to record a DEVICE Mac address, if you can get it, or the hardware ID, if it's unique. the store this to ensure you have the correct device on the server side, encrypted, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, you can actually use the NSNetServiceBrowser to query a list of bonjour services on the network like so

```
var dBrowser = NSNetServiceBrowser()
dBrowser.delegate = self
dBrowser.searchForServicesOfType("_hap._tcp", inDomain: "")
```

and in the NSNetServiceBrowser resolved delegate method you can access the ip address in the returning service's addresses property.

Link here for more info: http://dev.eltima.com/post/99996366184/using-bonjour-in-swift